# Pointer array is forcing programme to crash

Tags: c++, arrays

I wanted to pass an array pointer to a function and show content of that array from that function.I did this in below way but when i run the code the whole program is crashing.Please help me or give me idea how to solve this problem...

```
  int main()
    {
        int size,i;
        cout<<"Please enter the size of the array";
        cin>>size;
        int *array_=new int [size];
        cout<<"Please enter all elements of the array";
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            cin>>array_[i];
        }
        insertion(&array_,size);
        return 0;
    }
    void insertion(int *array_[],int size){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            cout<<*array_[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are passing the address of a pointer variable here: `insertion(&array_,size);`. As you want to pass the pointer just change to: `insertion(array_,size);`

Comment: No.It' showing an error.I think that part was right.

Comment: Try  cout<<(*array_)[i];

Comment: @TanvirRahman Well, the signature of `insert()` is also wrong, should be `void insertion(int *array_,int size){`. Otherwise it expects an array of pointers.

Comment: Yes i found it....:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void insertion(int *array_,int size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<array_[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the way you did it was correct as well, although not used very often. However operator[] has precedence over operator*, so the correct code would be  `cout << (*array_)[i]`.

Comment: Thanks it is working in your way also.If you want, you can write it in answer section.I will accept is as answer of this question...:)

Comment: _@TanvirRahman_, @rozina I would certainly downvote such answer, because it's totally confusing and not necessary. Stay with what you have now.